# Identify a TV show featuring exploration of a Spaceship

Tags: story-identification, tv

I used to watch a TV show in the 80s. In the show, the main characters used to explore a giant space ship having lots of chambers and in each chamber, there were a new group of people and situations and aliens. I can't remember what our heroes were looking for, but they used to end up in a new chamber (containing new situation and problem) each week.

Can you please identify that TV show?

Comment: The question had very poor English. I rewrote it entirely. If it has lost meaning somewhat, tell me.

Comment: This is a good question, by the way. I am interested to know the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [70s or 80s scifi TV show with people travelling between sections of large spaceship](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8257/70s-or-80s-scifi-tv-show-with-people-travelling-between-sections-of-large-spaces)

Comment: even earlier duplicate candidate at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/what-70s-60s-tv-show-tv-movie-had-a-generation-ship-whose-inhabitants-did-n/3616#3616

Answer (score 19):

Could this be *[Starlost](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069638/)*? The main premise of the show was that a group of generation travelers (from a 'primitive zone') are forced to explore a vast spaceship in order to work out how to restart their engines and prevent life-support from going off after an accident destroys the crew areas.

Each week they would enter new areas of the ship, either biospheres with different cultures or engineering areas and would face challenges as they made their way to the bridge.

Comment: I watched this a few months back, and it was actually pretty good, some good writing.  Most of the famous Sci-fi writers associated with the show disowned it later, but compared to what is normally on TV it was pretty solid.