# Title of spaceship-centered show

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

A very large crew wakes up aboard an intelligent spaceship and don't know how it works.  Slowly they learn the ship's system as they hurtle towards different existential threats, as politics break out among passengers.  They may be survivors of a lost Earth?  Aired around 2000 - 2010.  Can't find it anywhere.  Was a US production, though I think the engineer (or the guy who figured things out about the ship)  was Scottish.

Comment: Large crew? So, not [Dark Matter](http://io9.com/this-weeks-tv-six-strangers-wake-in-space-with-amnesia-1709749971) then

Comment: Possible dupe? Much too late, though; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/what-70s-60s-tv-show-tv-movie-had-a-generation-ship-whose-inhabitants-did-n

Comment: [Deepwater Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepwater_Black)?

Comment: @MarkRogers - No Scots on the crew and as far as I'm aware, only 6 people.

Comment: Still wishing they hadn't cancelled that show.

Comment: I KNOW THIS!! I read the book - it will come to me eventually.

Comment: If this helps, The reason nobody can remember, is because the computer that stored all of their memories was taken out by a meteor/asteroid

Comment: @RozzA That's definitely a story I've read, but I don't know if it was ever made into a show. I think that's a separate question - I can't remember or figure out what it was.

Comment: @RozzA I don't think its a match for this question, but are you thinking of Maria V Snyders [Inside Series](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Inside-Out-Story-Book-Insiders-ebook-x/dp/B004JHY5BK/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1445865647&sr=8-1&keywords=inside+out+maria+v+snyder)?

Comment: @RozzA: If you mean Mostly Harmless by Douglas Adams, there are more obvious things to remember.

Comment: @Chris: Sir, you are correct (I read those books a good 18 years ago..)

Answer (score 20):

[Stargate Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Universe) hits a lot of your hints.

- Series started in 2009.
- A large bunch of people take a Stargate and arrive on the ship Destiny.  They did survive an exploding planet, but it's not Earth.
- They don't control the ship at all, and it's more or less on autopilot, but is intelligent enough to try and help them survive.
- Robert Carlyle is Scottish and his character was more or less in charge of figuring out how the ship worked.

Comment: It does rather sound like someone's confused Dark Matter and SGU in their heads.

Comment: This isn't actually 100% true in they do get control over parts of the ship and also over the flight systems

Answer (score 1):

This could be [Andromeda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_(TV_series)), although it's only a little similar.

**Hits**

> an intelligent spaceship

The ships AI (Andromeda, or Rommie in her android form) is intelligent.

> Aired around 2000 - 2010

Andromeda ran from 2000 - 2005

> politics break out among passengers

There are several different species aboard the ship, from the Highguard commander Dylan Hunt; to the Magog Priest Rev Bem. Each have their own agendas.

**Misses**

> A very large crew

Andromeda was crewed by only 6 Initially

- Dylan Hunt
- Beka Valentine
- Tyr Anasazi
- Seamus Harper
- Trance Gemini
- Rev Bem

> wakes up

The Andromeda is caught in a black hole, causing time distortion aboard. Whilst several hundred years pass normally, mere moments pass for the ship. Additionally, only Dylan Hunt was aboard the ship originally, the rest of the crew formed a salvage team that pulled it out of the black hole.

> Slowly they learn the ship's system

Dylan is aware of the ships systems and how they work, but the others need to discover it - almost all of this happens off-screen though.

> I think the engineer (or the guy who figured things out about the ship) was Scottish.

The Ships engineer is Seamus Harper, who was from Boston on Earth. His accent is fairly different from the other crew, but it wasn't Scottish.