# Name of old tv show where they find out they are actually living in one pod on a spaceship and the crew is all dead?

Tags: story-identification, tv

Does anyone remember the name of an old tv show where they find out they are actually living in one pod on a spaceship and the crew is all dead.  Each pod has evolved into a different type of world.

Comment: a little more info would be useful please. was it in english? how old is old? 60's 70s 80s 2000s? A wild stab in the dark would be The Starlost. take a look at this see if it is familiar... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ars0DCQijqU&list=PLmAyiwH3Lpit9Aaud3XyzGMDNzkrOp0x5

Comment: Found it, thanks to this website!  The Starlost 1973

Comment: That's awesome. Would you be so kind as to click the green tick top left of my answer to acccept it. This is the first answer I ever wrote for this site.

Answer (score 17):

I think this is [*The Starlost*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Starlost), a Canadian TV show:

> Foreseeing the destruction of Earth, humanity builds a multi-generational starship called Earthship Ark, 50 miles (80 km) wide and 200 miles (320 km) long. The ship contains dozens of biospheres, each kilometres across and housing people of different cultures

Comment: @ Judith Jones beat me to it by seconds!!!!!! but I think you are correct!

Comment: And if so, a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/what-70s-60s-tv-show-tv-movie-had-a-generation-ship-whose-inhabitants-did-n

Comment: @Ian Kemp. Was the link I included not allowed? Would you be so kind as to explain why?Should I add where the quote is from?

Comment: @JudithJones: Ian just edited you answer to (1) switch to a regular-link, instead of mobile-only link and (2) make it an hyper link (we can now click on "The Starlost") rather than putting the link verbatim. Nothing to worry about, just a cosmetic change making the answer more concise and idiomatic. If you click on "edited X ago" you can see the revision history of your answer to see exactly the changes that happened.

Comment: Thanks for explaining 